# Best way to push data in a Google Sheet from html form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I have a simple html form:

```
<label for="phone">Phone: </label> <input id="phone" type="text" /><br />
<label for="address">Address: </label><input id="address" type="text" /><br />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

And a JS code that I'm trying to complete, to push data in a GSheet (I already created the application and obtained a working link like https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec).

```
    <script>

    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    var sample = document.getElementById("sample");
    var clear = document.getElementById("clear");

    submit.onclick = function(){
      var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
      var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

    // i'm lost!

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the values of certain cells in the spreadsheet, you'll need to first declare a variable ss to specify which spreadsheet you're using. There are a couple ways:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
```

this will work fine if you're initiating the script from the spreadsheet. However, I assume the script will be triggered by a form submission, in which case you'll need to specify the URL of the spreadsheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ ... /edit")
```

Next, specify what sheet and range to output your results into. For example, let's say you want to put the value `3` into cell `A1` of sheet `Sheet1`, these are just some possiblilites:

```
ss.getRange("Sheet1!A1").setValue(3)
```

or

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")

sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(3)//could use A1 notation
sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(3)//or could use row, column
```

If you want to set multiple cells at once, use `.setValues()` instead of `.setValue()` and make an array of arrays like so:

```
var values = [[1,2],[3,4]]

sheet.getRange("A1:B2").setValues(values)
//again, could use A1 notation

sheet.getRange(1,1,2,2).setValues(values)
//this is (upmost row, leftmost column, number of rows, number of columns)
```

The inner arrays are rows, so this will set up `A1:B2` like so:

```
      A     B
   +-----+-----+--
 1 |  1  |  2  |
   +-----+-----+--
 2 |  3  |  4  |  
   +-----+-----+--
   |     |     |
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your kind answer. Actually I need to push all data from the form (8 fields) in the first free row..

Comment: To add a row at the end of the sheet containing an array of values, use `sheet.appendRow([1,2,3,4])`

Comment: Oh, does it need to be the first blank row, or is it ok to just delete all the rows you're not using and add new rows each time?